# Python - Determine first iteration of loop

Tags: python, loops

I hae some code that reads in a file, skips the first line and then field splits every line.  On the first pass (ie -  the first line) I want to record the length of field split to a variable.  I know I can do it like this with a counter variable but is there a cleaner way?

```
line_count=1
for line in line_split[1:]:
        field_split = line.split(b'\t')
        if line_count=1:
            number_of_fields=len(field_split)
        line_count=line_count+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace defining the `line_count` with an enumerator:

```
for line_count, line in enumerate(line_split[1:]):
    field_split = line.split(b'\t')
    if line_count == 0:
        number_of_fields=len(field_split)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number_of_fields=len(line_split[1].split(b'\t')) if len(line_split) > 1

for index, line in enumerate(line_split[1:]):
   # Do whatever with index and line
```

This is optimal because it evaluates `if` only once. And by using `enumerate` on list you can get both index and item of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line_count, line in enumerate(line_split[1:], 1):
    field_split = line.split(b'\t')
        if line_count == 1:
            number_of_fields = len(field_split)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to detect the first line, you could do it like this -

```
first_line = True
for line in line_split[1:]:
    field_split = line.split(b'\t')
    if first_line:
        number_of_fields = len(field_split)
        first_line = False
        continue
```

The 'continue' will skip the rest of the block and move to the next line immediately.